# How to download csv file by giving location in Tkinter python (csv generated by converting dataframe to csv)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, tkinter, export-to-csv, filedialog

I am trying to download a CSV file in `tkinter` by selecting location and filename to save CSV file generated from dataframe by using the code. But instead of saving file like this, I want to choose location using `tkinter` to save my file.

```
   data = {
            'ans': list1, 'p': list2, 'td': list3
        }

        df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        df.to_csv('filenotpath.csv', header=False, index=False)

        df.to_csv(r'E:\fileHOpath.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: you'll need to pass a location argument to the dataframe `.to_csv` argument

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename) to select the output file:

```py
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
import pandas as pd

...

filename = asksaveasfilename(filetype=[('CSV files', '*.csv')])
if filename:
    data = {'ans': list1, 'p': list2, 'td': list3}

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    #df.to_csv(filename, header=False, index=False)
    df.to_csv(filename, index=False)

...
```

Comment: but now the problem is ,it is contiviously asking save file even after closing that window for many time ,and the data in exel file is filled only for two rows

Comment: My answer only shows that you can use `asksaveasfilename()` to select output file.  As you didn't post a [mre], how can we know why you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

First you can define a function that takes to two arguments with a dataframe (df) and a status from your tkinter entry (BooleanVar).

```
global save_status
save_status = False

def save_file(data, status):    
    global save_status
    save_status = status 
    
    if save_status:
        file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".csv",
                                                filetypes=[("csv file", ".csv")],
                                                )
        data.to_csv(file_path, sep = ";", index = False, decimal = ",")
```

Then you can call this function after `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`, as shown in my case below:

```
data = np.array([mvol, mcurr])
data = data.transpose()
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Voltage [V]", "Current [A]"])
# save file using status
save_file(data, self.save.get())
```

Here, `self.save.get()` is boolean value whose change depends on the status of checkbox as shown below:

```
self.save = tk.BooleanVar(value = False) 
save = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text = "Save Data", 
                       variable = self.save, onvalue = True, offvalue = False)
```